Can't assign numerical value to numerical template string in typescript
In typescript, I want to assign a number variable to a string variable that only accepts numerical strings. I tried the following:
const x: number = 0;
const y: `${number}` = x.toString();

But instead of resolving to ${number} type, it instead resolves to string type, which of course is not assignable to ${number}, even though number variables should always resolve to numerical values when stringified.
Without type assertion, is there a way to do it?

I  think you should write : const y: ${number} = ${x};

@ArnaudFlaesch Yes, that's exactly right! Thanks! Can you post it as an answer please?

I think you should write:
const y: `${number}` = `${x}`;

